# Proving the image of this function is closed when given a closed set.

Tags: real-analysis

Number 7 of [this released exam](https://math.berkeley.edu/sites/default/files/pages/F03_Final_Exam-D.Sarason.pdf) states:

> Let $f : \mathbb{R}^k \to \mathbb{R}^m$ be a continuous function such that $f^{-1}(K)$ is compact whenever $K$ is a compact subset of $\mathbb{R}^m$. Prove that $f(C)$ is closed whenever $C$ is a closed subset of $\Bbb{R}^k$.

I feel like my proof is wrong because I do not use the fact that $f^{-1}(K)$ is compact whenever $K$ is a compact subset of $R^m$.

My attempt is as follows:

Assume otherwise, $C$ is closed but $f(C)$ is not closed. This would mean $\exists a$ not in $f(C)$ such that $a$ is a limit point of $f(C)$. Consider a sequence that converges to $a = f(a_n)$  But then $f^{-1}f(a_n) = (a_n) \in C$ and since $C$ is closed there exists a sequence $(a_n) = a'$ as $f$ is continuous $\lim f(a_n) = f(a')$. But then $f(a') = a$ as limits are unique. So $a \in f(C)$. Contradiction. Hence $f(C)$ must be closed.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose $y_n \to y$ with $y_n \in f(C)$. Let $x_n \in C$ be such that
$y_n = f(x_n)$.

Note that $K= \{y_n\}_n \cup \{y\}$ is compact, hence $f^{-1}(K)$ is compact.

Since $x_n \in f^{-1}(K)$, there is a convergent subsequence, $x_{n_k} \to x$.
Since $C$ is closed, we have $x \in C$. Since $f$ is continuous, we have
$y_{n_k}=f(x_{n_k}) \to f(x)$, and since $y=f(x) \in f(C)$
we have the desired result.

Comment: So in essence I should reverse this and say that $x_n \to x$ and $x_n \in f(C)$ then I can create a compact set $A = \{x_n\}_n \cup \{x\}$ and feed it to $f^{-1}$. We are given that $f^{-1}(A)$ is must be compact. Since $f^{-1}$ is continuous, $f^{-1}(x_n) \to f^{-1}(x)$ and $f^{-1}(x_n) \in C$. But since $f(A)$ is compact $f^{-1}(x) \in C$ and so $x \in f(C)$. Then $f(C)$ is closed.

Comment: I just do not understand how $f(A)$ is compact since $f$ is continuous.

Comment: Continuous functions map compact sets into compact sets.

Comment: Actually I misread the question, but can't delete it from my phone.

Comment: So I can't just reverse your logic then? :(

Comment: @Dair: I repaired the logic.

Comment: @Dair, just to clear things up. Recall that $f:\Bbb{R}^{k} \to \Bbb{R}^{n}$. If $K\subset \Bbb{R}^{n}$ The set $f^{-1}(K)=\{x \in \Bbb{R}^{k}: f(x) \in K\}$. This set doesn't have necessairily only one element (you should ask $f$ to be biyective.) So be careful when talking about $f^{-1}(x_n)$ as if it where a unique element. It is usually a whole set.

Answer (score 0):

What you are missing is that a sequence in a closed set must have a limit point. (Not clear why "as $f$ is continuous" is relevant here, since everything is happening in $C$).

To solve the problem (which is not trivial): Firs, note that a subset of $\mathbb R^m$ is closed if its intersection with every closed ball centered at the origin is closed. Then, let B be a closed ball (centered at the origin) in $\mathbb R^m$. Show that $f(C) \cap B = f(C \cap f^{-1}(B))$. $f^{-1}(B)$ is compact because $B$ is compact, so $C \cap f^{-1}(B)$ is compact (because $C$ is closed), and since the image of a compact set by a continuous function is compact, this means that $f(C \cap f^{-1}(B))$ is compact. So $f(C) \cap B$ is compact, and therefore closed, in $\mathbb R^m$.